# Struts 1 Action Return Success After Downloading a Binary File

Tags: java, web, struts-1

I know how to download a binary file from my web app by setting the response header and copying the binary file to the response's outputstream.  But what I'm having trouble with is returning success so the page will reload.  If I return success I will get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been
>   called for this response

See the below code example.  This will download the file and then throw the exception.  Is there a way to restore the response?

```
public ActionForward export(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

    //tell browser program going to return an application file 
    //instead of html page
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=temp.csv");
    IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream("/path to some file"), response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();

    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do a redirect or reload after a file download.  This is more of an HTTP restriction, not something specific to Struts 1.

It takes one HTTP response to download a file to a browser, and one HTTP response to reload the page.  You are attempting to do both from the same HTTP request, which simply isn't possible.  A request cannot have more than one response.

In much the same way, you can't issue a redirect after you've served a page to the user, unless the page itself contains a `<meta refresh="...">` element or some JavaScript that does a reload.  Both approaches essentially create another HTTP request, but neither approach is open to you because it's not possible to do either with a file download.

In short, it's not possible to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Is there a way for me to know that the download has completed?  I want to show a dialog and then close the dialog when the download is complete.

Comment: @user2316479: as far as I know, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can set response.setHeader("Refresh", "1"); according to this article:

http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~buffa/cours/internet/POLYS/servlets/Servlet-Tutorial-Response-Headers.html

But it doesn't work when you close browser file download popup.